# How can I tell if a component received slot content?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slots

I have a component with an optional `slot`, and I need it to behave slightly differently if it received content in the slot vs. if it doesn't. How can I programmatically determine if a component received content in its slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the `onslotchange` event; just assume by default that no content is present, and if you get an event, you can now assume that it has content.

```
<slot name="demo" onslotchange={handleSlotChange}></slot>
```

...

```
handleSlotChange(event) {
  this.slotHasChanged = true
}
```

---

You can also use `this.querySelector` or `this.querySelectorAll` to query the slot's contents (note: this is different than `this.template.querySelector` and `this.template.querySelectorAll`, which queries only elements physically present in the Shadow DOM for the current component).

For named slots, you can also query the slot's content with:

```
this.querySelector(`*[slot='name']`)
```

Or:

```
this.querySelectorAll(`*[slot='name']`)
```

Comment: That's the direction I was thinking of after I asked the question. I'm just a bit surprised, I guess, that I can't do something like `this.slots`.

Comment: And this doesn't work too well if I had _two_ slots and wanted to know which one got slotted.

Comment: @Chuck The slot that got changed is the `event.target`; my example was overly simplified.  I found a potential workaround (at least, it works in LWC OSS), you can use something like `this.querySelector("*[slot='name']")` to find the content for a named slot, if that helps.

Comment: That's really good info. I'll try it in the morning.

Comment: Why do you say `onslotchange` fires if a slot has content? I'm not seeing it fire when first rendering the parent component